# Reusable setup and teardown functions before each test?

Tags: selenium, webdriver-io

My background is mostly Selenium's python implementation, so I'm new to JavaScript and WebdriverIO.  Forgive me if this is an elementary level question

Right now, there's a chunk of code  before() => {} block that is being copied/pasted at the beginning of teach /test/specs file, but I want it refactored out into a single setup function with that I can call that is shared across all test files so it is more maintainable and configurable.

I couldn't find any sources in the documentation stating what the best practice is for reusable functions for WDIO.  What's the standard for creating a setup and teardown function?

Answer (score 0):

Setup and teardown hooks can be configured in the wdio configuration file

https://webdriver.io/docs/configurationfile.html

```
    /**
     * Gets executed before test execution begins. At this point you can access to all global
     * variables like `browser`. It is the perfect place to define custom commands.
     * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
     * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that are to be run
     */
    before: function (capabilities, specs) {
    }
```

If these don't meet your needs, you'll have to do as you've mentioned, i.e. move the duplicated code into a function in a separate module and import it where needed.